# How can I add/subtract the value of ANY cell within a column by 1 using a button?:

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I found the script:

```
function increment() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue() + 1);
}
```

But this is limited to a specific cell. How can I alter this formula so I can select any cell and hit the button to increase by 1?

Answer (score 1):

Select any cell can be translated as "use the ActiveCell" (`getActiveCell()`).

---

```
function wa135765() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var value = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(+value+1)  
}
```